# error when remove a whitespace before a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, format

I would like to build a variable body1 use variable url1 in python 2.7

```
url1 = "http://somewebpage"
```

and 
     `body1 ={'url':url1}` 
give me a whitespace after the colon,

```
{'url': 'http://somewebpage'}
```

but when I use

```
body1 ={'url:{}'.format(url1)}
```

or

```
body1 ={'url'+':'+str(url1)}
```

to remove the space, it gives

`set(['url:http://somewebpage'])`

as the wrong output, how to avoid to be a set? what I want is just

`{'url':'http://somewebpage'}`

there should no space after colon.

Comment: Do you want a dict, or a string that contains the `{` and `}` characters along with everything between?

Comment: The space you got with `{'url':url1}` isn't part of the dict; it's just there to make the printed representation a bit neater. The dict contains no spaces, or colons, or braces. It has a key `'url'` mapped to a value `'http://somewebpage'`.

Comment: I want something exactly like this:  {'url':'http://somewebpage'}

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: this is how a `dict` formatted on output. If you want to print literally `{'url':'data'}`, use string formatting: `"{'url':" + repr(url1) + "}"`

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a data structure and its default printed representation, then.

Comment: @lynn You mean you want the string `"{'url':'http://somewebpage'}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body1 = { 'url:{}'.format(url1) }`

You are creating a string through `format`, then implicitly creating a `set` with the `{}` notation, which is syntactic sugar for the explicit `set()`.

`body1 = { 'url': url1 }`

The `{}` notation, when used with `:`, implicitly creates a dictionary instead of a set, which is printed to you (for visualization purposes) as `{'url': 'http://somewebpage'}` when you do `print(body1)`.

You are mistaking the dictionary string representation for the string that you want to generate. You don't want to generate any data structures. You just want to format a string that by chance looks like Python's printed representation of a dictionary.

Here is what you want: `body1 = "{'url':'" + url1 + "'}"`

I might add, that the use case seems a bit strange to me. OP, if you're trying to create a JSON string, Python has functionality in the `json` module to convert a dictionary to a JSON string with `json.dumps({'url': 'http://somewebpage'})`.

Comment: `json.dumps(dict)` creates a JSON string from a dictionary object. You don't need to reinvent the wheel :)